# SELECT from multiple tables with cross-references and self-references [brain cracker]

Tags: mysql, sql

Anyone up to an SQL challenge? Cause all my efforts so far are barely enough to simplify the problem and put it in a question...

Here it goes. In the example below we need to include:

- All *paid flights*
- *Flights to a country (paid or not)* if a person has made another flight to a paid city in that country

It's already tricky, but there is more to it.

- If a person flies to a city with no entry fee, but it is located in a
  country that DOES have a fee, that flight is still considered paid
  and must be included as well.

[image]
**EDIT:** *I've added flight 110, which should help reveal unnecessarily added free fligts.*

Below is the result set that should come out of the SQL query:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| Desired result set                                           |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| FlightNumber | ID | Name | LocationID | location.Name        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| 102          | 2  | Tom  | 500        | NL - NoFee           | -> because Tom has a paid flight to Amsterdam
| 103          | 2  | Tom  | 501        | Amsterdam (NL) - Fee | -> because Amsterdam is a paid location
| 105          | 4  | Bob  | 501        | Amsterdam (NL) - Fee | -> because Amsterdam is a paid location
| 107          | 6  | Bill | 503        | ITA - Fee            | -> because ITA is a paid location
| 108          | 7  | Ryan | 503        | ITA - Fee            | -> because ITA is a paid location
| 109          | 7  | Ryan | 505        | Venice (ITA) - NoFee | -> because Venice is located inside ITA
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Does anyone know how get this sweet result set with SQL?

**A good place to start:**

```
SELECT flights.FlightNumber, people.ID, people.Name, flights.LocationID, locations.Name
FROM flights
INNER JOIN people ON (people.ID = flights.ID)
INNER JOIN locations ON (locations.LocationID = flights.LocationID)
```

**CREATE/INSERT**

```
CREATE TABLE `people` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) );

CREATE TABLE `locations` (
  `LocationID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `EntryFee` TINYINT(1) NULL,
  `ParentLocationID` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`LocationID`) );

CREATE TABLE `flights` (
  `FlightNumber` INT NOT NULL,
  `ID` INT NULL,
  `LocationID` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`FlightNumber`) ,
  INDEX `fk_purchases_buyers_idx` (`LocationID` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_flights_people1_idx` (`ID` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_purchases_buyers`
    FOREIGN KEY (`LocationID`)
    REFERENCES `locations` (`LocationID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_flights_people1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ID`)
    REFERENCES `people` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);

INSERT INTO `people` (`ID`, `Name`) VALUES 
(1, 'John'),
(2, 'Tom'),
(3, 'Kate'),
(4, 'Bob'),
(5, 'Mike'),
(6, 'Bill'),
(7, 'Ryan');

INSERT INTO `locations` (`LocationID`, `Name`, `EntryFee`, `ParentLocationID`) VALUES 
(500, 'NL - NoFee', 0, NULL),
(501, 'Amsterdam (NL) - Fee', 1, 500),
(502, 'Rotterdam (NL) - NoFee', 0, 500),
(503, 'ITA - Fee', 1, NULL),
(504, 'Rome (ITA) - Fee', 1, 503),
(505, 'Venice (ITA) - NoFee', 0, 503);

INSERT INTO `flights` VALUES
(100, 1, 500),
(101, 1, 502),
(102, 2, 500),
(103, 2, 501),
(104, 3, 500),
(105, 4, 501),
(106, 5, 502),
(107, 6, 503),
(108, 7, 503),
(109, 7, 505),
(110, 6, 502);
```

*Unimportant note: I know this example is not completely logical in a sense of storing countries and cities in the same table and having flight records to a country and to a city. But this is just an example. At least it's more readable than `t1.col1`-like stuff.*

Comment: So your question is how to walk up the parent hierarchy for locations?

Comment: I'll give you a hint:  The second condition encompasses the first.

Comment: @RC. The hierarchy is fairly flat in this case (max 1 level deep), which is perfectly reflected by Country>City example. Cities have parent Countries, but there cannot be city within a city, or country within a country. The question is more about selecting paid-only flights and only related free flights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following should work :

```
SELECT F.FlightNumber, P.ID, P.Name, F.LocationID, LOC.Name AS Loc_Name
FROM flights F
INNER JOIN people P ON P.ID = F.ID
INNER JOIN (SELECT L1.LocationID, L1.`Name`, L1.`ParentLocationID` 
            FROM locations L1 
            LEFT JOIN locations L2 ON L1.`ParentLocationID` = L2.LocationID 
            WHERE L1.`EntryFee` = 1 OR L2.`EntryFee` = 1) AS LOC ON LOC.LocationID = F.LocationID
UNION 
SELECT F.FlightNumber, PAID_FL.ID, PAID_FL.Name, F.LocationID, PAID_FL.Loc_Name 
FROM flights F
INNER JOIN (SELECT F.FlightNumber, P.ID, P.Name, LOC.Name AS Loc_Name,LOC.`ParentLocationID` AS LocationID
            FROM flights F
            INNER JOIN people P ON P.ID = F.ID
            INNER JOIN (SELECT L1.LocationID, L1.`ParentLocationID`, L2.`Name` 
                        FROM locations L1
                        LEFT JOIN locations L2 ON L1.`ParentLocationID` = L2.LocationID 
                        WHERE L1.`EntryFee` = 1 OR L2.`EntryFee` = 1) AS LOC ON LOC.LocationID = F.LocationID) PAID_FL ON F.ID = PAID_FL.ID AND F.LocationID = PAID_FL.LocationID
```

Comment: CptMisery : Your query will also work except (Flights to a country (paid or not) if a person has made another flight to a paid city in that country).  In this your query will return flights to non paid cities in that country too.

Comment: Could you explain why CptMisery's approach won't return those? I admit the data set I provided in the description may not cover all possible combinations of relations, but with this dataset both of your approaches return the same rows. Except yours is differently ordered due to UNION...

Comment: INSERT INTO `flights` VALUES (110, 5, 501)     do this and you will know

Comment: I was sending Bill to Rotterdam while you were writing this comment :) It kind of revealed this too.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't do any testing, but I think this will work:

```
SELECT F.FlightNumber, P.ID, P.Name, L.LocationID, L.Name
FROM flights F
INNER JOIN people P ON P.ID = F.ID
INNER JOIN locations L ON L.LocationID = F.LocationID
WHERE P.ID IN (SELECT F.ID FROM flights F INNER JOIN locations L ON L.LocationID = F.LocationID WHERE L.EntryFee = 1)
```

[See it at SQLFiddle.com.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32ed2/3)

Comment: There is an error somewhere. MySQL doesn't give much debug info except `near '' at line 5`. Could you check it? There is also sqlfiddle.com tot test live, but it didn't work today (yesterday it did) :/

Comment: Haven't used sqlfiddle before. So I'm not yet sure how to share what I just did over there, but this query does work using the DB schema you have above. Edit: I also changed the capitalization for some of the columns in my query.

Comment: @Alph.Dev That particular error usually implies an unequal number of opening and closing parentheses

Comment: It was a copy-error on my side. Sorry about that! Your query actually returns the desired result set exactly! I need some time to process why it works...

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @CptMisery Your SQL returns all flights from people that have at least one paid flight to ANY country. That's not what I intended to get and not quite what I asked, but I think it's what I actually want. Thank you! I'll leave meet's answer as accepted for the reference, because it matches the question more precisely.

Comment: Oh sorry. Overlooked that part.

Comment: @CptMisery I'm glad you did. This is better than I expected. Also, at a first glance it seems faster. Can you confirm?

Comment: Mine is definitely faster than @meet's answer, but you're both right that it doesn't give you exactly what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.*
     ,  COALESCE(y.entryfee,x.entryfee,0) fee 
  FROM locations x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN locations y 
    ON y.parentlocationid = x.locationid;
```

Comment: This just returns all locations. I don't get it. How does this help?

Comment: This returns a 1 for all locations where any part of that location path has an entryfee (except it doesn't because I slightly stuffed up the query)